# How to create github or stackoverflow authentication in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created an test app for multiple providers authentication in ASP.NET Core. Already have created authentication for Microsoft, Google, Facebook and Twitter but I don't know how to create authentication with GitHub or Stackoverflow.

```
.AddFacebook(options =>
            {
                options.AppId = "your appId";
                options.AppSecret = "your appSecret";
            })
            .AddTwitter(options =>
            {
                options.ConsumerKey = "your ConsumerKey";
                options.ConsumerSecret = "your ConsumerSecret";
            })
            .AddMicrosoftAccount(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = "your Microsoft ClientId";
                options.ClientSecret = "your Microsoft ClientSecret";
            })
            .AddGoogle(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = "your Google ClientId";
                options.ClientSecret = "Your Google ClientSecret";
            })
```

Comment: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication

Comment: https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/

Comment: I know the docs pages from GitHub and Stack Overflow but in fact I need how to call the client_id and client_secret. We have 4 methods like `AddGoogle` or `AddTwitter`. What method need to use for GitHub client_id and client_secret?

Comment: hay man, I have a UWP app, But i havent been successful in applying authentication for multiple providers and acknowledge that authentication for one user. I there a way i could see your authentication architecture to learn how to do it please? @Llazar

Comment: The solution is for ASP .NET Core Mvc not for UWP check the code in GitHub maybe can help you https://github.com/llgjermeni/IdentityApp-SocialProvider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution and implemented in code. GitHub authentication can be done with the method `.AddOAuth()`. A possible implementation could be:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {....      })
       .AddOAuth("GitHub", options =>
            {
              options.ClientId = Configuration["GitHub:ClientId"];
              options.ClientSecret = Configuration["GitHub:ClientSecret"];
              options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-github");
            }
```